# Execute a command in another terminal via /dev/pts

Tags: linux, stdin, pts

I have a terminal that uses `STDIN 3` (`/proc/xxxx/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/3`)

So if (in another terminal) I do:

```
echo 'do_something_command' > /dev/pts/3
```

The command is shown in my first (`pts/3`) terminal, but the command is not executed. And if (in this terminal `pts/3`) I'm in a program waiting for some data from `stdin`, the data is written on screen but the program does not capture it from `stdin`.

What I want to do is execute the command `"do_something_command"` and not only show it.

Can someone explain this behavior to me? How do I achieve my intention?

Comment: Do you need to press enter in `/dev/pts/3` after receiving data?

Comment: I tried it... if I do enter on terminal (pts 3) after sending data to /dev/pts/3 only the enter is received. not the "do_something_command". it's like it never exists... only showed.

Comment: the real intent is to control mpg123 -R from another terminal. but i'm curious about the pts functionality and what can or can't do with it. and why.

Comment: hum... not a solution for this, but the mpg123 command has a fifo param, that create a named pipe to solve my problem.

Comment: You may want to look at xdotool. A pts doesn't really act like a pipe.

Comment: It'a nice tool, but it's only for Xorg, my intent is a way to do it in ssh connections, for example.

Comment: OK. Then you can achieve what you want by using a program that uses the TIOCSTI ioctl to simulate terminal input. There are several examples on stackoverflow.com, in several languages. I don't know which languages you prefer, so try the search box to find **TIOCSTI** and see if one looks alright.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I completely get what you are asking. You can achieve this by writing and executing a small piece of code in C yourself. This should give you some idea.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_help(char *prog_name) {
        printf("Usage: %s [-n] DEVNAME COMMAND\n", prog_name);
        printf("Usage: '-n' is an optional argument if you want to push a new line at the end of the text\n");
        printf("Usage: Will require 'sudo' to run if the executable is not setuid root\n");
        exit(1);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *cmd, *nl = "\n";
    int i, fd;
    int devno, commandno, newline;
    int mem_len;
    devno = 1; commandno = 2; newline = 0;
    if (argc < 3) {
        print_help(argv[0]);
    }
    if (argc > 3 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'n') {
        devno = 2; commandno = 3; newline=1;
    } else if (argc > 3 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] != 'n') {
        printf("Invalid Option\n");
        print_help(argv[0]);
    }
    fd = open(argv[devno],O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("open DEVICE");
        exit(1);
    }
    mem_len = 0;
    for (i = commandno; i < argc; i++) {
        mem_len += strlen(argv[i]) + 2;
        if (i > commandno) {
            cmd = (char *)realloc((void *)cmd, mem_len);
        } else { // i == commandno
            cmd = (char *)malloc(mem_len);
        }

        strcat(cmd, argv[i]);
        strcat(cmd, " ");
    }
  if (newline == 0)
        usleep(225000);
    for (i = 0; cmd[i]; i++)
        ioctl (fd, TIOCSTI, cmd+i);
    if (newline == 1)
        ioctl (fd, TIOCSTI, nl);
    close(fd);
    free((void *)cmd);
    exit (0);
}
```

Compile and execute it with `sudo` permissions. For example, if you want to execute a command on `/dev/pts/3`, then simply do a `sudo ./a.out -n /dev/pts/3 whoami`, runs a `whoami` on `/dev/pts/3`.

This code was completely taken from [this page](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/).

Comment: so what should i do to open interactive shell of another terminal?

Comment: Also if you want a better understanding of this I'd suggest `man ioctl_tty` and pay attention to the `TIOCSTI` option.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the wrong quotes around the command.
Either remove the quotes and the echo command, or use echo and back-ticks (`).

Try:

```
echo `date` > /dev/pts/3
```

or just

```
date > /dev/pts/3
```

Note that whatever runs on /dev/pts/3 wouldn't be able to read what pops up "from behind".

Comment: Thanks but it's not i'm looking for... your suggestion only redirects the output of command to /dev/pts/3, what I'm trying to do is execute the command in /dev/pts/3.